# Force Scrollbars Images CSS

Tags: css, image, html-table, scrollbars

How would I accomplish the following without the use of tables?

If I don't wrap the imgs in tds the scroll bars aren't forced.

The imgs are pushed down like regular text with out the tds.

I have tried setting the imgs to display:block, inline-block and a couple other ideas but I'm clueless.

http://jsfiddle.net/zjews/

Edit: I could apply inline-table to the wrapped "a" links but unfortunately internet explorer doesn't support this property.  Does anyone know of a way to emulate inline-table in internet explorer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is this what you mean?: http://jsfiddle.net/SebastianPataneMasuelli/zjews/1/

i wrapped the links and images in a container div,
and then simply gave the div the style `white-space:nowrap;`,
which i'm pretty sure is read by all browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the images in container elements such as divs. Apply `overflow: auto; width: 200px; height: 200px;` to those containers, for example.

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap all the images in a container div and give that a fixed width.  Then force the x axis to overflow.

something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/3n6nm/1/

Comment: Thanks, for the reply.   Basically I have a different number of images every time ranging in various sizes.  That is what I was trying to avoid.  If that could work I would do it.